# Не остановить секундомер(requestAnimationFrame)

Tags: javascript

Добрый день\вечер\ночь\утро. Прошу вас указать мне на логические ошибку\ки в этом коде. Упреждая возможный ход событий, подчеркиваю - **логические**, **в этом**. Итак, проблема - таймер останавливается лишь визуально, то есть при повторном клике на кнопку старт, можно убедиться, что он не останавливался.
А хотелось бы наблюдать корректную его работу.  Благодарю за внимание.

```js
(function() {
  let hours = document.querySelector('.hours'),
    minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes'),
    seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds'),
    milliseconds = document.querySelector('.milliseconds'),
    start = document.querySelector('.start'),
    pause = document.querySelector('.pause'),
    stop = document.querySelector('.stop'),
    pointTime = Date.now(),
    timer;

  const startTime = () => {
      let diffTime = Date.now() - pointTime;
      start.disabled = true;

      milliseconds.textContent = ((diffTime % 1000).toString().length === 1) ?
        `00${diffTime%1000}` :
        ((diffTime % 1000).toString().length === 2) ?
        `0${diffTime%1000}` :
        diffTime % 1000;

      seconds.textContent = ((Math.floor(diffTime / 1000) % 60).toString().length === 1) ?
        `0${Math.floor(diffTime/1000)%60}` :
        Math.floor(diffTime / 1000) % 60;

      minutes.textContent = ((Math.floor(diffTime / 60000) % 60).toString().length === 1) ?
        `0${Math.floor(diffTime/60000)%60}` :
        Math.floor(diffTime / 60000) % 60;

      hours.textContent = (Math.floor(diffTime / 3600000).toString().length === 1) ?
        `0${Math.floor(diffTime/3600000)}` :
        Math.floor(diffTime / 3600000);


      timer = requestAnimationFrame(startTime);

    },
    stopTime = () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(timer);
      hours.textContent = minutes.textContent = seconds.textContent = `00`;
      milliseconds.textContent = `000`;
      start.disabled = false;
    },
    pauseTime = () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(timer);
      start.disabled = false;
    };

  start.addEventListener('click', startTime);
  pause.addEventListener('click', pauseTime);
  stop.addEventListener('click', stopTime);

  window.onunload = () => {
    start.removeEventListener('click', startTime);
    pause.removeEventListener('click', pauseTime);
    stop.removeEventListener('click', stopTime);
  }
})();
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

.module-timer {
  text-align: center
}

.module-timer,
.bts-trigger {
  margin-top: 10px
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="module-timer">
  <span class="hours">00</span><span class="separator">:</span><span class="minutes">00</span><span class="separator">:</span><span class="seconds">00</span><span class="separator">:</span><span class="milliseconds">000</span>
  <div class="bts-trigger">
    <button class="start">start</button>
    <button class="pause">pause</button>
    <button class="stop">stop\reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так если и не запускать таймер сразу, а допусти, через 10 секунд, то и отсчёт начинается с десятой секунды.
Сделайте ресет для `pointTime`. Определите функцию для клика, где вы сделаете ресет и запустите функцию `startTime`

Comment: в этом случае дельта  постоянно будет равна нулю. И таймер не будет работать.

Comment: Да, я изменил ответ

Comment: Прошу прощения, мозг уже не варит - немного не понял ответ

Comment: Ну смотрите. Вы pointTime определяете только при загрузке скрипта. И далее вы оперируете им только в функции startTime. Вам нужно при клике на start проверять в каком состоянии находится таймер. Если таймер на паузе - продолжить. Если таймер остановлен или ещё не запущен - ресетнуть pointTime. У вас сейчас даже при первом старте таймера он уже не верное значение показывает.

Comment: благодарю Вас. Доперло.